# short code got changed in visual mode in wordpress

Tags: php

I am inserting a php short code for widget in wordpress page in text mode. But when i go to visual mode and then again to text mode then my short code converts into comments.
Eg: This is my short code :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-4'); ?>
```

and it converts into:

```
< !--?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-4'); ?-- >
```

after this my short code does not work.

Please get me through out this problem.

Comment: That's not a short code, that's a block of php. You cant insert a block of php directly into a post

Comment: See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score -1):

`<!-- HTML Comments Go Here -->` in HTML. PHP executes before it's HTML on the Client. Your sidebar code should be within PHP tags like: `<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-4'); ?>`. Notice that your code is not PHP at all, since you don't have the tags right. You just have a useless HTML comment.

Get rid of that comment altogether.

```
<ul id='sidebar'>
  <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-4'); ?>
</ul>
```

The documentation was very clear: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Comment: will u please tell me how to fix that code same in both visual as well as text mode in wordpress page.

Comment: I tried to help. I don't use wordpress, but the documentation was very clear.